# How to send properly a message in twilio conversation with react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, twilio

I have a nextjs project and I want to replace the twilio programmable chat with twilio conversations.

I did the following steps:

1. I did one API which [creates](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/quickstart) or gets (if it is already created) the conversation and returns to the client the c**onversation unique name** and the [**token**](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/create-tokens)
2. Once I have the conversation unique name and the token I want to send client side one message.

To do so I did the following function:

```
import { Client, State } from '@twilio/conversations';
import toast from 'react-hot-toast';

const sendMessageToConversation = async (
  token: string,
  room: string,
  message: string
) => {
  const client = new Client(token);
  client.on('stateChanged', async (state: State) => {
    if (state === 'initialized') {
      try {
        const conversation = await client.getConversationByUniqueName(room);
        await conversation.join();
        if (message && String(message).trim()) {
          await conversation.sendMessage(message);
        }
      } catch {
        toast.error('Unable to create conversation, please reload this page');
      }
    }
  });
};
```

the problem seems to be `const conversation = await client.getConversationByUniqueName(room);` which gives the following error:

[image]

What do you think I did wrong?

Also is it a better idea to build an API to send messages [in this way](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-message-resource)? I would avoid this because of the possible overhead of the server

***UPDATE***

I tried to send a message [through API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-message-resource). It works and it returns what I expect. For more detail I will put also the code I have on backend side which generates the tokens and the conversations.

I generate tokens for client side with:

```
import Twilio from 'twilio';
import { config } from '../config';
const client = require('twilio')(
  config.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  config.TIWLIO_AUTH_TOKEN
);

const AccessToken = Twilio.jwt.AccessToken;
const ChatGrant = AccessToken.ChatGrant;
const SyncGrant = AccessToken.SyncGrant;

export const tokenGenerator = (identity: string) => {
  const token = new AccessToken(
    config.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
    config.TWILIO_API_KEY,
    config.TWILIO_API_SECRET
  );

  token.identity = identity || 'unknown';

  if (config.TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID) {
    const chatGrant = new ChatGrant({
      serviceSid: config.TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID,
      pushCredentialSid: config.TWILIO_FCM_CREDENTIAL_SID,
    });
    token.addGrant(chatGrant);
  }

  if (config.TWILIO_SYNC_SERVICE_SID) {
    const syncGrant = new SyncGrant({
      serviceSid: config.TWILIO_SYNC_SERVICE_SID || 'default',
    });
    token.addGrant(syncGrant);
  }

  return {
    identity: token.identity,
    token: token.toJwt(),
  };
};
```

I create conversations with:

```
const client = require('twilio')(
  config.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID,
  config.TIWLIO_AUTH_TOKEN
);

export const createTwilioConversation = async (
  partecipantsProfiles: Partial<User>[],
  identity: string
) => {
  const friendlyName: string = partecipantsProfiles
    .map((el) => `${el.first_name} ${el.last_name}`)
    .join(' - ');

  const conversation = (await client.conversations.conversations.create({
    friendlyName,
    uniqueName: uuidv4(),
  })) as TwilioConversationResponse;

  await client.conversations
    .conversations(conversation.sid)
    .participants.create({ identity });

  return conversation;
};
```

The flow I do in order to send messages is:

- If I want to send a message I create a conversation by calling an API, executes the functions above and returns the room unique name and the token. I also store into my DB the room unique name, participants and other infos. I do this only for the first message. If a user has already chatted with another user, then I don't create a conversation anymore, but I return the unique name stored + token generated and I get/send the message client side

I have also tried to send a message through API and it works. I can't figure out why I still can't get the conversation by unique name client side. Maybe I should generate the token differently?

This is the method that sends messages server side:

```
export const sendMessage = async (
  conversationSid: string,
  author: string,
  body: string
) => {
  return await client.conversations
    .conversations(conversationSid)
    .messages.create({ author, body });
};
```

Comment: Not sure if it's causing the error, but a constructor cannot return a promise, so you cannot `await new Client(token);`. The error you have there says "Not Found", do you definitely have the right conversation name?

Comment: Hello @philnash! I just updated my question. In fact the "await" keyword is useless, but even after removing it, it doesn't work anyway. I also tried to send a message backend side through API and it works. At this point my doubt is that I don't get the token correctly? Take a look to the updated question if you want. Thank you very much!

Comment: You only create one of the participants in the conversation. Should you be creating both?

Comment: Hi @philnash I tried adding also my identity, but It doesn't work anyway. I found a repo on github (https://github.com/twilio/twilio-conversations-demo-react). In this demo they create the conversation client side. Do you think I have to change the flow? I am stucked on this with my project since 2 weeks ago :\

Comment: You don't have to create conversations client side, it's fine to create them on the server. What I don't get is how the line `const conversation = await client.getConversationByUniqueName(room);` is causing the error in your screenshot, as it lies within a `try/catch` block.

Comment: @philnash should the `tokenGenerator` be the problem? If I log the client just before to get the conversation by unique name I have this (https://ibb.co/s3wt99D). As you can see I am connected but if I take a look to the "conversations" attribute I can see there are zero elements. Also this (https://ibb.co/c28t232) is the conversation I created with RESP API. I just cannot figure out why there are no conversations yet...

Comment: another thing is that here (https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/api/conversation-resource#conversation-properties) they use a specific `messagingServiceSid` instead of an `uniqueName` should I do like that? After that should I do something else in ChatGrant?

Comment: If you're just using Conversations to replace Chat, and you don't have SMS/WhatsApp participants, then you don't need to worry about a Messaging Service.

Comment: When you connect to the Conversations SDK, the client represents your participant, and if they haven't yet joined a conversation then there will be no conversations shown. Your code shows that you are trying to join the conversation after fetching it, which should be correct. I'm still wondering why you get a React error message when you say the error is caused by code that is within your own `try/catch` block. Are you sure that's where the error is from?

Comment: @philnash Actually the react error as it is in the screenshot comes out if I pull out from the `try/catch` block the line "await client.getConversationByUniqueName(room)`. I did it to show more details. Anyway there comes out the toast that's in the catch block so the behaviour is basically the same.

Comment: What happens if you keep it in the try/catch, but log out the error object? Are you able to dig into any further messages or information that it has about what went wrong?

Comment: If I get and print the error into the catch block I get this (https://ibb.co/SXbR94B) which is basically the same error show in the screenshot.

Comment: Ok, when do you call the `createTwilioConversation` function? Particularly, when do you call it in relation to trying to get that room and join it in the client side?

Comment: @philnash When I want to send a message to someone I go to his profile and press "Send Message" button -> I write the message I want and press "Send" -> I call an API that gets the conversation unique name from my local DB, if not present I call the method `createTwilioConversation` I create it and I store that into my DB and return to the backend the unique name  + token. After that I use client SDK to send the message. So I call `SendMessageToConversation` with the unique name, token and message. Keep in mind that this flow was working with programmable chat.

Comment: I keep the conversations in my db because it is easier for me to handle the lists and also has a vision of the conversation participants without using the sdk.

Comment: @philnash I just did a sample project on github to simulate exactly the same error I have into my project. Also here I got the same error... Take a look if you want https://github.com/Tricabit/twilio-conv-test

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that project and see what I can do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are not using the default Conversations service, but you are not scoping your API calls on the server side to the service you need.

So in `pages/api/utils/conversations` you need to add `.services(config.TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)` into all your API calls. See below:

```js
export const createTwilioConversation = async (
  chatTo: string,
  myIdentity: string
) => {
  const uniqueName = uuidv4();

  const conversation = (await client.conversations
    .services(config.TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)
    .conversations.create({
      friendlyName: `Chat created by ${myIdentity}`,
      uniqueName,
    })) as TwilioConversationResponse;

  await client.conversations
    .services(config.TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)
    .conversations(conversation.sid)
    .participants.create({ identity: chatTo });

  await client.conversations
    .services(config.TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)
    .conversations(conversation.sid)
    .participants.create({ identity: myIdentity });

  return conversation;
};

export const sendMessage = async (
  conversationSid: string,
  author: string,
  body: string
) => {
  return await client.conversations
    .services(config.TWILIO_CHAT_SERVICE_SID)
    .conversations(conversationSid)
    .messages.create({ author, body });
};
```

Once you've done that, you need to one other thing. Because you add your participant to the conversation using the REST API, you don't need to `join` the conversation in the front-end. So you can remove the line

```js
await conversation.join();
```

from `src/twilio/index.ts`.

One last thing, you can get better error messages in the front-end if you log out `error.body` rather than just `error` or `error.message`.

```js
      try {
        const conversation = await client.getConversationByUniqueName(room);
        if (message && String(message).trim()) {
          await conversation.sendMessage(message);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        console.log("error body", error.body);
        toast.error("Unable to create conversation, please reload this page");
      }
```

Answer (score -2):

Twilio have an official blog for **Build a Chat App with Twilio Programmable Chat and React.js**, please check it out once,

Here is the link - https://www.twilio.com/blog/build-a-chat-app-with-twilio-programmable-chat-and-react

Comment: Twilio programmable chat will be replaced by conversations definitely in July. So That will not work anymore in 6 months.